# How can I solve java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, android

Getting the following error in Android Studio:

[image: Gettingfollowing error in the android studio]

Getting:

> java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type com.example.glide.ImageList cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[] in this line

Code:

```
ArrayList<ImageList> list = new ArrayList<>();
Object[] objNames = list.toArray();
String[] strNames = Arrays.copyOf(objNames, objNames.length, String[].class);
for(int j=0; j < strNames.length; j++){
    strNames[j] = String.valueOf(list.get(j));
    Log.d("String : {} ", strNames[i]);
}
```

Comment: ArrayStoreException in Java. ArrayStoreException in Java occurs whenever an attempt is made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. You storing ImageList to String. TRY TO SAVE IN ImageList.class . What exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has lots of logical mistakes.

But try this one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ImageList> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new ImageList()); //adding some dummy objects, you add yours
    list.add(new ImageList());
    String[] strNames = new String[list.size()];
    for(int j=0; j < strNames.length; j++){
         strNames[j] = String.valueOf(list.get(j));
         Log.d("String : {} ", strNames[i]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a list of ImageList items. 
Second, this list is empty.
Third, you have defined an Array of String , and use Array.copyOf to populate it.

This won't work.  You can cast ImageList to String directly.
What is that you are trying to achieve here?

Not sure, if you want a string representation of ImageList you can iterate over your "list" and call the .toString() method on each instance  so you get the string representation of your instance.

Again not clear what you want?